# How to improve the ability to problem solving in mathematical analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, problem-solving

I recently learn Mathematical Analysis by Zorich and feel ok with theorems and examples in the book, however I'm stuck when do exercises in Problems in mathematical analysis by Kaczor, I refer to solutions and find that there are plenty of details that seem to come from vacuum, for example, to prove an inequality the author use a transformation of binomial formula and I don't understand what is the original idea of using such formula, how can one get to this detail from the beginning and step by step without consulting the solutions. Is there any suggestion? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the theorem which uses the binomial formula? Maybe it would be useful to analyze that particular example in depth. You could edit the question with the trascription of the statement and the proof of it.

Comment: More than in algebra, (real) analysis has a lot of "tricks of the trade",  but there are a few basic blocks , one of these being the different forms of Taylor expansions in particular the generalized binomial expansion of $(1+X)^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha$ non-integer.

Comment: Why don't you answer to the question asked by Tortar ?